# How to retrieve the alfresco ticket generated after Logging in using Rest API from Java?

Tags: alfresco

I could Login into alfresco using ALfresco REST API. I am doing it through java class.
Also am able to get the response message as 'OK'. But can any one please tell me how to retrieve the ticket generated while logging in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a ticket, you would usually call `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/login` -  (or similiar) - either GET or POST:

Try this:

```
curl -XPOST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}' http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/login
```

It returns a JSON data structure:

```
{
        "data":
        {
                "ticket":"TICKET_3c255a809fadbf8abddd0546cbe354c2ab6d3995"
        }
}
```

Or a basic GET:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin'
```

which returns an XML document holding the ticket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ticket>TICKET_6f997d0e561b07430c19043d7c42783d08b02489</ticket>
```

That said, just in case you want a higher level abstraction dealing with low level communication issues like authentication, session, timeouts etc., you might want to have a look at the spring webscripts connector framework. https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/spring-surf-parent/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/connector/AlfrescoConnector.html might be a good entry point. Have a look at Alfresco share to see how it is used in detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it like the example with the commons HttpClient described in the java example here: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Login,

then the ticket can be found in the body of the response (method.getResponseBodyAsString();) which looks exactly like @andreas-steffan shows in his answer. You just have to parse the json response.

Answer (score 2):

Below Is java function for same.

```
private static String getAlfticket() throws IOException, JSONException { 
        String ticket = ""; 
        URL url = new URL("http://hostname/alfresco/service/api/login u="+USERNAME+"&pw="+PASSWORD+"&format=json"); 
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection(); 
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream(); 
        String encoding = con.getContentEncoding(); 
        encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding; 
        String json = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding); 
        JSONObject getData = new JSONObject(json); 
        System.out.println(getData.getJSONObject("data").get("ticket") 
                .toString()); 
        ticket =getData.getJSONObject("data").get("ticket").toString(); 
        return ticket; 
    }
```

Below is similar link.In that also I have answered question.

"[Alfresco login api giving Bad Request 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399016/alfresco-login-api-giving-bad-request-400/26401560#26401560)"